# Optimum use of Concurrent Collections with Threads Vs. Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, collections, concurrency, task

I've been reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on MSDN about C# Concurrent Collections. It talks about the optimum threading to use for particular scenarios to get the most benefit out of the collections e.g:

> ConcurrentQueue performs best when one dedicated thread is queuing and one dedicated thread is de-queuing. If you do not enforce this rule, then Queue might even perform slightly faster than ConcurrentQueue on computers that have multiple cores.

Is this advice still valid when one is using Tasks instead of raw Threads? From my (limited) understanding of C# Tasks, there is no guarantee that a particular Task will always run on the same thread between context switches, or does maintaining the stack frame mean that the same rules apply in terms of best usage?

Thanks.

Comment: That optimisation only applies to very very small loops, the very next sentence says *"When processing time is around 500 FLOPS (floating point operations) or more, then the two-thread rule does not apply to ConcurrentQueue<T>, which then has very good scalability. Queue<T> does not scale well in this scenario."*

Comment: Say for example that the work threads are fetching URLs from the web, then this rule does not apply.

Comment: Understood that this is probably nit-picking for the vast majority of cases, I guess I'm just trying to understand a bit more about how Tasks are implemented under the hood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One task always runs on the same thread. TPL is a user-mode library. User mode has no (practical) way of migrating executing code from thread to thread. Also there would be no point to doing that.

This advice applies exactly to tasks as it does to threads.

What that piece of advice means to say is that *at the same time* there should be one producer and one consumer only. You can have 100 threads enqueuing from time to time as long as they do not contend.

(I'm not questioning that advice here since that is out of scope for this question. But that is what's meant here.)

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that a single task will always run on the same thread.